# Take in a character and output its ASCII hex value

Tags: c, arduino, microcontroller, avr, atmega

I'm programming (in C) my own serial functions for a UART on an ATMEGA microcontroller and I need to have the user input a single character and have it output its ASCII hex value,

i.e. if the user types an 'a', the output would be '0x61'. I wrote a function called

`putvalue(unsigned char ch)`,

which takes in a single character and displays it to the screen, so now I just need to write a function which takes in the character and converts it to the characters which correspond to its ASCII hex value. So far I've done the following:

```
void puthexvalue(unsigned char ch) {
    putvalue(0x30) \\writes a '0' to the screen
    putvalue(0x78) \\writes an 'x' to the screen
    unsigned char ch1 = ch & 0xF0;
    unsigned char ch2 = (ch & 0x0F) >> 4;
```

So now I have the numerical values of the characters I want to print in `ch1` and `ch2`, but I'm not sure how to actually find the ASCII value that corresponds to these numbers and print THAT value.

Any hints or help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: It should be `ch1 = ch & 0xf0 >> 4`  and `ch2 = ch & 0x0f`.

Comment: "So now I have the numerical values of the characters I want to print in `ch1` and `ch2`" No, you don't. At least `ch2` is zero and it is not the numberical values you want to print.

Comment: @MikeCAT ah you're right. in the original code i had it the other way around, just accidentally wrote it for 0F instead od F0 in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character codes from `'0'` to `'9'` are guaranteed to be continuous in C specification.

Character codes from `'A'` to `'Z'` and from `'a'` to `'z'` are continuous in ASCII code.

Therefore, if the number is between 0 and 9, you can get ASCII code by adding `'0'` to the number.
If the number if between 10 and 15,you can get ASCII code by adding `'A'` or `'a'` to the number minus 10.

Also your calculation of `ch1` and `ch2` are wrong: `ch1` is multiplication of 16 (because lower bits are cleared) and `ch2` will be always zero (because bits other than last 4 bits are cleard, then shifted right 4 bits).

The implementation including fixed calculation of `ch1` and `ch2` will be like this:

```
char getHexChar(unsigned char c) {
    if (c <= 9) return '0' + c;
    else if (c <= 15) return 'A' + (c - 10);
    else return '?';
}

void puthexvalue(unsigned char ch) {
    putvalue(0x30); //writes a '0' to the screen
    putvalue(0x78); //writes an 'x' to the screen
    unsigned char ch1 = (ch & 0xF0) >> 4;
    unsigned char ch2 = ch & 0x0F;
    putvalue(getHexChar(ch1));
    putvalue(getHexChar(ch2));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was super helpful! Just for reference, I did have the original as the F0 value shifted right four bits, I just accidentally switched it when I wrote this question and didn't notice.

Comment: And can I just ask why your default return is return '?'  ? Is that because the '?' symbol is special in ASCII or is it just to return a ? when a symbol that isn't supported is entered?

Comment: It is just returning `?`. You can use your favorite character as fallback.

Comment: cool. but i just wanna confirm that it shouldn't really ever NEED to fallback to that right? bc ideally i would like my program to work for all possible entered characters

Comment: Hmmm, the fallback isn't needed because `ch1` and `ch2` will only be between 0 and 15 thanks to the mask. `char getHexChar(unsigned char c) { return c <= 9 ? '0' + c ? 'A' + (c - 10); }` will work.

Comment: for some reason that's giving me an 'expected ':' before ';' token' error?

Comment: Sorry, I made typo. `char getHexChar(unsigned char c) { return c <= 9 ? '0' + c : 'A' + (c - 10); }`

Comment: instead of `'A' + (c - 10)` it is better to be `c + ('A' - 10)`, because `('A' - 10)` is a constant, and whole expression will be compiled as the only one operation. While `'A' + (c - 10)` requires two operations